# EXCEL VBA : How to validate value with isString or isNumeric?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code below:

```
Dim m As String, n As Long

n = InputBox("Enter sales amount: ")

If n < 500 Or n > 5000 Then
ActiveCell.Value = n
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
m = InputBox("Reason why increase/decrease? ")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = m
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Else
ActiveCell.Value = n
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
```

I was figuring out how do I validate value if input was string then inputbox will prompt and ask for integer ? 
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code:

```
Dim m As String, n As String, sales as long
TryAgain:

n = InputBox("Enter sales amount: ")

If Not IsNumeric(n) Then
    MsgBox "Entry should be a number!"
    GoTo TryAgain
End If

sales = CLng(n)

If sales < 500 Or sales > 5000 Then
ActiveCell.Value = sales
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
m = InputBox("Reason why increase/decrease? ")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = m
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Else
ActiveCell.Value = sales
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
```

Comment: Hi ! What if I want to put validation too in "reason why increase/decrease" ? if integer was an input then gonna ask for string

Comment: From a business needs standpoint that will be much more difficult.  Would you reject 5, but accept awuifbouiqebv?

Comment: Sorry, but does my second question sounds impossible to code? please give me some tips. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think that it will be possible to vaidate something that is free text.  You'll have to decode what your business rules are for the response and test for all of those.  I doubt testing if it's a number will actually satisfy the business requirements.